# How do I correctly use captured groups from sed in my replacement text?

Tags: sed

Just not enough of a sed user to be able to figure this out. I'm trying to convert from underscore to lodash, which requires changing many invocations from `_(obj).method()` to `_.method(obj)`. I've been trying to do this with sed using this:

```
sed "s/_(\(.*\)).\(.*\)(/_.\2(\1, /"
```

This pattern actually works fine for a single instance in a line. E.g.

```
echo "_(foo).bar('blah')" | sed "s/_(\(.*\)).\(.*\)(/_.\2(\1, /"
```

actually outputs the expected result: `_.bar(foo, 'blah')`. The problem is when there are multiple occurrences on a single line. E.g.

```
echo "_(foo).bar('baz') yep _(baz).quux('blah')" | sed "s/_(\(.*\)).\(.*\)(/_.\2(\1, /"
```

outputs `_.quux(foo).bar('baz') yep _(baz, 'blah')` and

```
echo "_(foo).bar('baz') yep _(baz).quux('blah')" | sed "s/_(\([^(]*\)).\(.*\)(/_.\2(\1, /"
```

outputs `_.bar('baz') yep _(baz).quux(foo, 'blah')`.

So, I obviously just don't understand exactly how to use capture groups in my replacement texts. And incidentally, adding `/g` to the end does not resolve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is this what you are looking for?

```
sed -r 's/_\(([^)]*)\)\.([^(]*\()([^)]*\))/_.\2\1,\3/g'
```

with your example:

```
kent$  echo "_(foo).bar('baz') yep _(baz).quux('blah')" | sed -r 's/_\(([^)]*)\)\.([^(]*\()([^)]*\))/_.\2\1,\3/g'
_.bar(foo,'baz') yep _.quux(baz,'blah')
```

#### update, comments on your codes:

I took a look on your codes, and did some modification, now it works here.

```
Yours : sed "s/_(\([^(]*\)).\(.*\)(/_.\2(\1, /"
Mine  : sed "s/_(\([^)]*\))\.\([^(]*\)(/_.\2(\1, /g"
```

- keep in mind, sed does always greedy match, so, you have to use `[^something]`. check the places I changed.
- dot (`.`) should be escaped when you want it to match literal `.`.
- `g` flag is needed

Comment: Potentially, though `-r` doesn't exist on Mac. Supposedly, the corresponding option is `-E`, but when I tried that (previously) it said something like about unmatched parentheses. Let me try your example though.

Comment: @tandrewnichols I have zero experience with mac, but I guess you meant bsd sed. I used `-r` because, we use grouping brackets more than literal brackets, I just want to save some escaping, you can remove the `-r` and escape those brackets.

Comment: Yeah, looks like it's working. Willing to accept your answer, though it would be helpful (for me anyway) to understand a) why mine didn't work, and b) why yours did. I like to learn. :) I'll try to read it, but reading sed regexes is difficult...

Comment: @tandrewnichols: yours didn't work because the `.*` is greedy and skipped over embedded `)` and then `(` characters in the source string, and Kent's code doesn't do that; it uses `[^)]*` to avoid gobbling `)` characters.

Comment: @tandrewnichols I just updated answer and add the fix  of your codes.

Comment: A couple thoughts. 1) the `[^(]` was actually just a typo. I used the opening paren. I think I would have been a dunce otherwise. 2) I thought I tried it with `\.` but maybe I had other mistakes at the time that kept it from doing the right thing. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @tandrewnichols the main cause is the `\([^(]*\)` after the `\.`